# Possible to generically remove function types from datatype, to allow deriveJSON?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, aeson

I have several datatypes representing the state of an application. In various places in the datatype, I have embedded functions or monadic actions, eg.

```
data Foo = Foo Int (ActionM String)
data Bar = Bar Foo (Maybe Bar) (ActionM ())
```

I need to encode most of these datatypes as json so I can send it to the browser for display. Using deriveJSON (from the Aeson package) doesn't work because instances for ActionM can't be derived. However, I don't actually want those bits to be sent anyway. I currently have an approach which works but is basically copy-pasting the full set of datatypes and manually removing the embeded ActionM fields.

I (think I) need one of a couple of things. Either

- a way to tell deriveJSON to just ignore fields that it can't figure out, and maybe parse them back into `undefined`. As far as I can tell this doesn't exist
- a way to automatically generate a parallel set of datatypes with these fields removed. So I want to write something like

`applyMagic Bar`

and get back

```
data Foo' = Foo' Int
data Bar' = Bar' Foo' (Maybe Bar')
```

Is any of this possible, and how would I do it?

Comment: If `ActionM` is a `data` or `newtype` you could just define a `ToJSON` instance for it which which encodes it as some simple JSON value (e.g. 0 or "".) Then you can auto-derive the ToJSON for `Foo`. It still wold contain an extra simple value, but it would save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplistic solution, but couldn't you do something like

```
data Foo' = Foo' Int

type Foo = (ActionM String, Foo')
```

and simply obtain the second element of the tuple when you want to serialize?

Tuples are an instance of [`ComonadEnv`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.6/docs/Control-Comonad-Env.html), so you could also use functions like `ask` and `extract`.

**Edit.** `Bar` is a more complicated case because it is a recursive type. But it could be handled using the [`CofreeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Comonad-Trans-Cofree.html) comonad transformer:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Bifunctor (second)
import Control.Comonad -- from 'comonad'
import Control.Comonad.Hoist.Class
import Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree -- from 'free'

-- Orphan ComonadHoist instance that will likely be added in future
-- versions of free
instance Functor f => ComonadHoist (CofreeT f) where
    cohoist g = CofreeT . fmap (second (cohoist g)) . g . runCofreeT

type Bar = CofreeT Maybe ((,) (ActionM ())) Foo
type Bar' = Cofree Maybe Foo'

applyMagic :: Bar -> Bar'
applyMagic = cohoist (Identity . extract) . fmap extract
```

`CofreeT Maybe ((,) (ActionM ())) Foo` is a non-empty list of `Foo` values that have been annotated with `ActionM ()` values.

`Cofree Maybe Foo'` is a non-empty list of `Foo'` values, without extra annotations (`Cofree Maybe Foo` is a synonym for `CofreeT Maybe Identity Foo'`, where `Identity` works as the trivial comonad.).

To transform one into the other, `applyMagic` first uses `fmap extract` to transform all the `Foo`s into `Foo'`s, and then uses [`cohoist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.6/docs/Control-Comonad-Hoist-Class.html) from `ComonadHoist` to remove the "annotation layer" underneath `CofreeT`.

In general, values with "extra context" can often be modeled with comonads.

Comment: how would you extend this to also cover `Bar`?

Comment: @ajp I have expanded my answer to cover `Bar`.